# How to write a simple batch file at startup to press ENTER

Tags: command-line-interface, startupscript

My first stack exchange post ;_;

I teach some graphic design at a school with a Windows 10 Lab. Over the summer the district implemented a privacy notice which requires you to press enter before it auto logs in.

Is there any way I can write a batch script to automate the enter keystroke to possibly make my life a little easier?

I am pretty new to all this. Any help is appreciated.

I have this written so far but it does not accomplish what I am hoping.

WScript.Sleep 10000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"